# hide cms block on checkout page if customer logged in

Tags: layout, ce-1.9.2.2, local.xml, cms-block

I want to hide my CMS block if customer is logged in. This is how my block is added to OPC page via `local.xml` file.

```
<opc_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="cms/block" name="cart_sinup" before="_">
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>signup</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</opc_index_index>
```

Note: I cannot use `<customer_logged_in>` because I want this only in opc_index_index page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by replacing the following xml

```
<opc_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="cms/block" name="cart_sinup" before="_">
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>signup</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</opc_index_index>
```

with

```
<opc_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="cart_sinup" before="_" template="ds/regaddress/opc_signup_wrapper.phtml" />
    </reference>
</opc_index_index>
```

in my local.xml and then create a new template file

> app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/ds/regaddress/opc_signup_wrapper.phtml

and add this code in it.

```
<?php 
    if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){  
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('signup')->toHtml(); 
    }
?>
```

What I'm doing here is rendering my cms_block in template file with the user logged in check and then adding this block via xml.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by using a css.

when you create a CMS Block assign a class or id to its container like `<div class="customer_login_condition">` and on `app\design\frontend\<YOUR_PACKAGE>\<YOUR_THEME>\template\page\html\footer.phtml` add the css like following at the bottom of phtml.

```
<?php
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
?>
    <style>
        .customer_login_condition {display:none;}
    </style>
<?php
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks @ashish Yes this would work but it is not the right solution since the whole block will rendered in every case and then displayed as none.

Comment: yes i am also looking for a perfect solution of this.i would love to here from some one expert for this.

Answer (score 0):

In success.phtml you could do:

```
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sinup');
}
```

Typo in "sinup", but I just matched yours.

This will output the block if customer is not signed in, if they are signed in it will simply continue.

Comment: CMS static blocks are not rendered by using getCHildHtml function!

Comment: @MuhammadSaiid actually they are, since you define a new block within content called "cart_sinup" containing the content of "cms static block signup" and you can simply call it by its name property, in this case "cart_sinup". Or you could add the "as" property and call it by that name instead.

Comment: I didn't have to getChildHtml( ) my block and it is still rendered on my opc_index_index page with only the layout xml I have written above.

Comment: @MuhammadSaiid yes that is actually true, since "content" is of "core/text_list", what other blocks do you have in handle "opc_index_index", maybe you could target that and use the if statement inside that block. EDIT: ok saw you found I solution