# Magento 2 change logic in layout if logged in

Tags: magento2, layout, conditional-loading

I have a block in a layout xml but I only want it to be displayed if the customer is not logged in. Is this possible?

Comment: Does your block have a phtml corresponding to it or its a cms block

Comment: Its a cms block

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways I can think to solve this. I am going to tell you how I would solve this issue but it may not suit your specific situation.

I would add a custom Layout Handle to not signed in customers, then add the block only in that layout.

This would allow me to add more blocks, customizations later to customers that are not signed in, additionally, it would allow me to more precisely tune my layout changes.

I would do an after plugin on whatever controller I needed the block to show up on in my example I am applying it everywhere:

```
\Magento\Framework\Controller\Index\Index::execute
```

Check if the customer is logged in by dependency injecting the following class to my Plugin controller:

```
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
```

Setting it as a property

```
$this->customerSession = $customerSession;
```

Adding that as a property to my plugin

```
protected $customerSession
```

And performing this check within afterExecute()

```
$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
```

The entire thing would look like this:

```
namespace YourCompany\YourModule\Plugin\Controller;

class LoggedIn
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param $object
     * @param $resultPage
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterExecute($object, $resultPage)
    {
        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $resultPage->getLayout()->
            getUpdate()->
            addHandle('customer_not_logged_in');
        }

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

After that, you can make a layout file the normal way named:

customer_not_logged_in.xml
Anything you change in this layout will only affect customers who are not logged in.

Caveats:

You may need to plugin a different controller. If for example, you want this to only apply to login pages you would instead of the CMS controller want to plugin afterExecute on the \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login controller.

This is not proposed as the best solution but it is the solution I would/have used to solve this type of issue. Your mileage may vary.

I did not show how to create a plugin using di.xml the documentation on how to do that is here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Good luck. & Have a good day.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the methods, mentioned here: [hide cms block on checkout page if customer logged in](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117733/hide-cms-block-on-checkout-page-if-customer-logged-in/117823#117823)

Just change the code compatible with Magento 2